# HTML5 Datetime-local input

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, input, datetimepicker

The problem arises in Google Chrome on android phones. There is no 24h format.

Example:
- when I click on datetime-local input I get a wheel to choose date and time. But there is no option to choose the full range of 24hours. I can't choose 23h or 17h.

I also dont have any option to choose from AM or PM.

My timezone is on my phone is set to GMT+2 and its set to 24h time.

EDIT: I would like to atleast know this , was there ever and option to choose from 0-24h, or was it always 12h range?

Comment: It's a bug of Chrome 45.  crbug.com/529320

Comment: Oh good to know I wasn't the one that messed this up. Whats not good is that I have no control over this. Gotta hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears there is currently a bug with type="datetime-local" 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=529320